# If $S_{n}=\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r+2 n}{n^{2}+r n}$ and $T_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{r+2 n}{n^{2}+r n}\right), n \in N,$ compare it with $1+\ln2$

Tags: integration

If $S_{n}=\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{r+2 n}{n^{2}+r n}$ and $T_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{r+2 n}{n^{2}+r n}\right)$, $n \in N,$ then How do $S_n$ and $T_n$ compare with $1+ln2$. I need to tell whether $S_n$ (> or <) $1 + ln$ and $T_n$ (> or <) $1 + \ln2$

**Approach:** The following summation can be written as $\int_0^1\frac{x+2}{x+1}dx = 1 + \ln2$ But I don't know how to proceed next. How do I compare $S_n$ and $T_n$ with this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the nature of the integrand. Over the interval $[0,1]$, it is monotonically decreasing. Now note that the Riemann summation $S_n$ occurs "from the right hand side", since $r$ starts from $1$ rather than $0$, so, for example, the first rectangle that we take has height $f(\frac 1n)$ instead of $f(0)$ where $$f(x)=\frac {x+2}{x+1}$$ and hence, since the integral is decreasing, the area taken for $S_n$ is less than the given integral for all finite $n$. However, for $T_n$ the situation is exactly the opposite. Hence $T_n>1+\ln 2>S_n$ should be your final answer.